# The difference between applying permissions to separate object and list of objects in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework

In my code permissions result differently to object and list of objects.

Let's say we have one model of `User`:

```
class User(auth.AbstractBaseUser, auth.PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

and two rows in db:

```
1. name = "Dennis", profile_status = "private" # (not "public")
2. name = "Robert", profile_status = "private" # (not "public")
```

and the viewset:

```
class UsersViewSet(viewsets.CreateListRetrieveUpdateViewSet):
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()            # doesn't matter...
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer   # doesn't matter...
    filter_class = filters.UsersFilterSet           # doesn't matter...
    permission_classes = [IsProfileAccessStatus('public'),
                          IsReadOnly]
```

`IsProfileAccessStatus('public')` django permission returns `True` if object's `profile_status` equals 'public':

```
def IsProfileAccessStatus(access_status=''):

    class IsProfileStatusOf(BasePermission):
        def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
            return hasattr(obj, 'profile_status') and \
                   obj.profile_status== access_status

    return IsProfileStatusOf
```

Back end returns users at `/api/users/` and speicific one at `/api/users/:name/`.

*Different output*

On `/api/users/Dennis/` drf returns exception according the `IsProfileAccessStatus('public')` permission. So it's okay.

But for `/api/users/` it returns both objects:

```
[
  { "name": "Dennis", "profile_status": "private" },
  { "name": "Robert", "profile_status": "private" }
]
```

So the question is Why django permissions are used this way? Why drf permissions are not applied for every instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expensive computationally to do this for every user. Imagine if you had hundreds of thousands of them. In the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#limitations-of-object-level-permissions):

> **Limitations of object level permissions**
>
> For performance reasons the generic views will not automatically apply
>   object level permissions to each instance in a queryset when returning
>   a list of objects.
>
> Often when you're using object level permissions you'll also want to
>   filter the queryset appropriately, to ensure that users only have
>   visibility onto instances that they are permitted to view.

A work around is probably just to override the list view and use `.filter(profile_status__exact='public'`

Comment: Thanks @erik-sn! Your answer really makes sense.